# Decimal multiplication ( primary school algorithms ) and relations to the Fourier Transform.

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis, convolution

I suppose most of us are familiar with multiplication algorithms for decimals numbers we learn in primary school. 13*13 = 3*13 + 10*13 = 169 what actually is performed in this case (but of course they don't tell the kids) is a convolution, thirteen "moves around" and is multiplied with a new digit at each new position and then everything is summed up. Although it can not be a "pure" convolution, since we must regard carry, which occurs if any number in the convolution becomes larger than 9.

So I guess my question would be, what more mathematics would we need to put these algorithms the kids learn into the language of convolutions and Fourier Transforms?

---

My own work so far is limited to just calculating divisions, sums and modulo 10 on the digits after the convolution. I do not know how to "translate" these operations into any more enlightening operations. I have learned some very basic abstract algebra, but I don't know how to use it in this context ( if it is applicable ).

Comment: Some of the fastest integer multiplication algorithms for very large integers use Fourier transforms (or Number-theoretic transforms, which are algebraically similar). Wikipedia has a pretty complete article about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods

Comment: Ah thank you! I knew there existed algorithms for approximating $\pi$ by using Fourier Transforms to speed up multiplications. That was around some time when that was a popular method to measure CPU speed I think. I will give it a try although my number theoretic skills are a bit limited :)